# xslt2: sequence of attribute nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0

This is not really a question but an astonishing xslt2 experience that I like to share.

Take the snippet (subtract one set from another)

```
<xsl:variable name="v" as="node()*">
  <e a="a"/>
  <e a="b"/>
  <e a="c"/>
  <e a="d"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:message select="$v/@a[not(.=('b','c'))]"/>

<ee>
  <xsl:sequence select="$v/@a[not(.=('b','c'))]"/>
</ee>
```

What should I expect to get?
I expected **a d** at the console and

```
<ee>a d</ee>
```

at the output.

What I got is

```
<?attribute name="a" value="a"?><?attribute name="a" value="d"?>
```

at the console and

```
<ee a="d"/>
```

at the output. I should have known to take $v/@a as a *sequence of attribute nodes* to predict the output.

In order to get what I wanted, I had to convert the *sequence of attributes* to a *sequence of strings* like:

```
<xsl:variable name="w" select="$v/@a[not(.=('b','c'))]" as="xs:string*"/>
```

Questions: 
Is there any use of *sequences of attributes* (or is it just an interesting effect of the node set concept)?
If so, would I be able to enter statically a *sequence of attributes* like I am able to enter a *sequence of strings*: **('a','b','c','d')**
Is there any inline syntax to convert a *sequence of attributes* to a *sequence of strings*? (In order to achieve the same result omitting the variable **w**)
It seems to be an elegant way for creating attributes using *xsl:sequence*. Or would that be a misuse of xslt2, not covered by the standard?

Answer (score 0):

As for "Is there any inline syntax to convert a sequence of attributes to a sequence of strings", you can simply add a step `$v/@a[not(.=('b','c'))]/string()`. Or use a `for $a in $v/@a[not(.=('b','c'))] return string($a)` and of course in XPath 3 `$v/@a[not(.=('b','c'))]!string()`.

I am not sure what the question about the "use of sequences of attributes" is about, in particular as it then mentions the XPath 1 concept of node sets. If you want to write a function or template to return some original attribute nodes from an input then `xsl:sequence` allows that. Of course, inside a sequence constructor like the contents of an element, if you look at 10) in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-complex-content, in the end a copy of the attribute is created.

As for creating a sequence of attributes, you can't do that in XPath which can't create new nodes, you can however do that in XSLT:

```
  <xsl:variable name="att-sequence" as="attribute()*">
      <xsl:attribute name="a" select="1"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="b" select="2"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="c" select="3"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

then you can use it elsewhere, as in

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <element>
              <xsl:sequence select="$att-sequence"/>
          </element>
          <element>
              <xsl:value-of select="$att-sequence"/>
          </element>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

and will get

```
<example>
   <element a="1" b="2" c="3"/>
   <element>1 2 3</element>
</example>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhg

XQuery has a more compact syntax and in contrast to XPath allows expressions to create new nodes:

```
let $att-sequence as attribute()* := (attribute a {1}, attribute b {2}, attribute c {3})
return 
    <example>
        <element>{$att-sequence}</element>
        <element>{data($att-sequence)}</element>
    </example>
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn56

Comment: super! your answer, Martin, sorts out several - hopefully all - of my quirks about nodes, values and sequence elements. All my questions have been answered.